# How to find adjacent / neighbor cubes using octree datastructure?

Tags: 3d, nodes, voxel, octree

I have created a boundary octree for a closed surface. All the octree cubes that contain the surface are divided up to the same level. So all the leaf nodes are of the same size. 
I need help in finding out the neighbors for each of these terminal cubes. 
I tried referring to different papers but could not figure out how to actually implement it..  in Matlab. 
Right now I treat all the terminal cubes as voxel cubes ( without using the octree data structure) and use brute force to find out which of the 26 possible neighbors are in the list of cubes which make up the surface. It is taking ages to get the output. I am new at programming so I would really appreciate if someone could suggest ways to find the neighbors of the leaf nodes more efficiently and how to implement the method by coding in matlab.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for this being late, but I implemented the neighbor finding algorithm for octree neighbor finding documented in Samet (1989). This is the link (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0734189X89900388) to the paper. For your purposes you need to see the finding equal sized nodes section of the paper.

Comment: Here is a version of the paper that is not behind a pay wall: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/pubs/SameCVGIP89.pdf